# No sound in windows 8 running on bootcamp

Tags: audio, drivers, windows-8.1, macbook-pro, boot-camp

After a few days of searching the web, I managed to install windows 8.1 on my computer successfully including the drivers. After I rebooted my macbook I noticed that my sound was not working. I checked my device manager and noticed that "High Definition Audio Controller" under System Devices is not working and cannot start. The error is "The device cannot start error 10".

Things I have tried:

- Tried adding the hardware through "Add legacy hardware" but it blue screens during install.
- Tried installing the drivers manually and downloading the drivers from cirrus or realtek.
- Re installed bootcamp drivers.

Note:

- I bumped into many problems when trying to install windows 8.1 on my mac. When I tried to install it on the partition that bootcamp made it would not install it since my partition style was a Master Boot Record. So I booted back into osx and made a empty unallocated space in disk utility and I would create the partition using the windows installer thus allowing me to install windows 8.1.
- I use EFI Boot (2 drives do not appear in my boot selection list. I only see Macintosh HD, EFI Boot and Recovery 10.9)
- I use a macbook 13 inch (Early 2011)

So is there anyway to fix this problem.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the BootCamp drivers for Win 8 to get your devices working.

Comment: I did use the bootcamp drivers. I got the drivers the the bootcamp assistant utility included with my mac.

Comment: Are you using BootCamp 5.1?

Comment: Yes I am using bootcamp 5.1 on osx mavericks

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly this issue - also on a 13" early 2011 MBP. It seems to be peculiar to the EFI install method - installing onto the pretend MBR as a BIOS-based boot, the drivers all work fine. Quite annoying, since performance is apparently better under EFI. But after hours attempting to find a solution to the problem, a BIOS install is the only way to go. Not looking forward to reinstalling personally...